# discountasp.net issue with PUT and DELETE for asp.net web api

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

I have a pretty standard asp.net web api set up with get post put and delete. I am hosting on discountasp.net. Works great for all verbs on localhost, when I deploy, only get and post are working. I have read just about every question regarding this topic, I have made sure that WebDav is disabled, and make sure my handler mappings are accepting the right verbs, and I and STILL get a 405 error.

Anyone know what the problem might be? It is mvc4 asp.net web api, pretty much out of the box, and I am using ajax on a single cshtml page to interact with all the verbs. My web server is iis7.

Comment: Look for webdav de-activation using config.

Comment: Ya that was the issue, I posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out it was a simple web.config change. Dont know why alot of the walkthroughs had me going into iis and messing with handlers and all that good stuff. I added this to the modules section of web.config and it works like a charm now:

```
<system.webServer> 
<modules … > 
<remove name="WebDAVModule" /> 
…… 
</modules>
```